# javascript brcrypt and java / jruby Bcrypt

Tags: java, javascript, bcrypt, crypt

I wanted to use Twin-bcrypt (a javascript lib) an the client side.
On serverside I use Jruby / java  in that case I use JBCrypt. The javascriptside is 2y salted the Javaside is 2a salted which seems to be buggy. Both are i my experience not compatible. 
(I just wonder why java which is used by enterprises has no up to date bcrypt). But is there any experience to hash a password with bcrypt with javascript on the clientside and compare it on the java serverside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [`jsBCrypt`](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/) for javascript. This is based on [`JBCrypt`](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) and as expected works well with it.

The snippet on `jsBCrypt` can help you get started with trying this. (note: [`JBCrypt` has default 10 rounds](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html)).